# Using dual isp and static ip

Tags: load-balancing, isp, static-ip, round-robin

what are the options to increase/backup bandwidth of a load balanced web farm gaining bandwidth from more isps?
What are hardware/ip requirement to benefict from the 2 lines?

http://s22.postimg.org/uosndocdd/net2.jpg

it is what i need? http://www.peplink.com/

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/325023/dual-isps-load-balancing/325032#325032

Answer (score 1):

For this, I will assume that you're a) a consumer, b) you don't have any provider independent IP addresses ranges or an assigned ASN, and c) you're using linux on your router or are at least willing to.

With multiple connections, you would be able to provide link redundancy, static routing over preferred egress routes, and the ability to load-balance connections over both connections but you wouldn't be able to capitalize on the sum of bandwidth from both internet connections over one session.

I did this once at home when I had a Cable internet connection as well as a fibre connection.  Cable was cheap and plentiful, but the fibre was oh so much faster and more reliable.  In my case, I decided to put all VoIP traffic over fibre and wholesale data transactions over cable.

I recall referencing [this](http://lukecyca.com/2004/howto-multirouting-with-linux.html) site to aid in my configuration.  I hope it helps!

Comment: it is windows based environment and this is what i mean http://s22.postimg.org/uosndocdd/net2.jpg

Comment: Well, the end clients on the LAN aren't consequential, I was referring to the router's OS being linux.  There is, of course, the hardware approach which would be like the comment below mentions ... a load balancer type unit in front of a router with multiple interfaces.  Some of Cisco's gear does multi-link load-balancing as it is.  I guess it's really a choice depending on your application/environment and budget.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Elfiq load-balancer units... These give you multi-WAN load balancing for inbound *and* outbound.

Covered in [Multi-WAN bonding across different media](https://serverfault.com/questions/401661/multi-wan-bonding-across-different-media/401683#401683)